# 特定のサイトに複数のコンテントファイルを反映させたいが、片方しか反映されない。

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

```
"manifest_version": 3,
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.test.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "test-1.js"
            ]
        },
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.test.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "test-2.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

例えば上記のようにマニフェストを設定すると、test-1のJSファイルは反映されず、test-2のJSファイルのみ反映されてしまいます。
どうにか両方反映させる方法はないでしょうか？
何卒よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

元の書き方だと match の定義が重複しているため、片方しか反映されないのだと思います。

以下の通り js の部分で配列として定義してみて下さい。

```
"manifest_version": 3,
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.test.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "test-1.js", "test-2.js"
            ]
    ],
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
その方法で試してみましたが、やはり後者のファイルしか反映されません・・・。
バグなんでしょうか・・・。